# How to prove that $\max(f(n), g(n)) = \Theta(f(n) + g(n))$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

> Using the basic definition of theta notation prove that $\max(f(n), g(n)) = \Theta(f(n) + g(n))$

I came across two answer to this question on this website but the answers weren't clear to me. Would you mind to elaborate how this can be proven? I am first year student of computer sciences. Thank  you!

Edit:

What  exactly does $\max(f(n), g(n))$ return?

Comment: It's not true in general without some condition, the most obvious being that both are positive functions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is "both are positive functions" the only condition? Am not able to guess any other condition for which above hold

Comment: You can refer to this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791306/prove-fn-gn-is-omaxfn-gn]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that $f(n) \leq f(n) + g(n)$ and $g(n) \leq f(n) + g(n)$. Hence, $$\max(f(n), g(n)) \in \mathcal{O}(f(n) + g(n))$$
Next note that $f(n) + g(n) \leq 2 \max(f(n),g(n))$. Hence, $$\max(f(n), g(n)) \in \mathcal{\Omega}(f(n) + g(n))$$
Hence, we get that
$$\max(f(n), g(n)) \in \mathcal{\Theta}(f(n) + g(n))$$

Note that
$$\max(f(n),g(n)) = \begin{cases} f(n) & \text{if } f(n) \geq g(n)\\ g(n) & \text{if } g(n) \geq f(n) \end{cases}$$
For instance, if $f(n) = 10n$ and $g(n) = n^2$, we get that
$$\max(f(n),g(n)) = \begin{cases} 10n & \text{if } n \leq 10\\ n^2 & \text{if } n \geq 10 \end{cases}$$

Comment: I think I'm starting to get the hang of it. So first we get the upper bound. However what I do not understand is the third and fourth line, namely, "Next note that f(n)+g(n)≤2max(f(n),g(n)). Hence,
max(f(n),g(n))∈Ω(f(n)+g(n))". Why is f(n) + g(n) < 2max(f(n), g(n)) ? Basically after we get the upper and lower bounds, we can get the running time, correct?

Comment: @Peter For a fixed $n$, if $f(n) \geq g(n)$, then we have that $f(n) +f(n) \geq f(n) + g(n) \implies f(n) + g(n) \leq 2 f(n)$ and if $g(n) \geq f(n)$, then we have that $g(n) +g(n) \geq f(n) + g(n) \implies f(n) + g(n) \leq 2 g(n)$. Hence, we get that $$f(n) + g(n) \leq 2 \max(f(n) + g(n))$$
The key observation is that $f(n) \leq \max(f(n),g(n))$ and $g(n) \leq \max(f(n),g(n))$ and hence $$f(n) + g(n) \leq 2 \max(f(n) + g(n))$$

Comment: That makes more sense. However, how did you get to f(n) + f(n) or g(n) + g(n) ?

Comment: For instance, if we have $f(n) \geq g(n)$ adding $f(n)$ to both sides, we get that $2f(n) \geq f(n) + g(n)$ and similarly for the other case as well.

Comment: Ok I'm off to try and figure this out to the core. Thanks for your help and time. Answer accepted

Comment: in the solutions to intro to algo.. exercises i found the following answer the my q. Part 1: "First, lets clarify what the function max( f (n), g(n)) is. Lets deÞne the function
h(n) = max( f (n), g(n)). Then
h(n) =
 
f (n) if f (n) ≥ g(n) ,
g(n) if f (n) < g(n) ."

Comment: Part 2: Since f (n) and g(n) are asymptotically nonnegative, there exists n0 such that
f (n) ≥ 0 and g(n) ≥ 0 for all n ≥ n0. Thus for n ≥ n0, f (n) + g(n) ≥ f (n) ≥ 0
and f (n)+g(n) ≥ g(n) ≥ 0. Since for any particular n, h(n) is either f (n) or g(n),
we have f (n) + g(n) ≥ h(n) ≥ 0, which shows that h(n) = max( f (n), g(n)) ≤
c2( f (n) + g(n)) for all n ≥ n0 (with c2 = 1 in the deÞnition of ).

Comment: Part 3: Similarly, since for any particular n, h(n) is the larger of f (n) and g(n), we have for
all n ≥ n0, 0 ≤ f (n) ≤ h(n) and 0 ≤ g(n) ≤ h(n). Adding these two inequalities
yields 0 ≤ f (n) + g(n) ≤ 2h(n), or equivalently 0 ≤ ( f (n) + g(n))/2 ≤ h(n),
which shows that h(n) = max( f (n), g(n)) ≥ c1( f (n)+g(n)) for all n ≥ n0 (with
c1 = 1/2 in the deÞnition of ).

Comment: I am probably wrong for saying this but somehow your explanation and this one don't look the same?

Comment: @Peter I do not understand why you you think mine is different from your textbook's solution. Both are in fact the same solution.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks for your help. So basically you get the upper bound, and the lower bound. Based on that we get Theta, correct?

Comment: @Peter No. I did not find you rude at all. Yes, if you look at my first comment, I have shown you how to obtain the inequality by making use of the fact that $f(n) \leq \max(f(n),g(n))$ and $g(n) \leq \max(f(n),g(n))$ and adding them both.

Comment: @Peter Yes. essentially you have that
$$\dfrac{f(n) + g(n)}2 \leq \max(f(n),g(n)) \leq f(n) + g(n)$$ and hence you conclude that $\max(f(n),g(n)) \in \Theta(f(n) + g(n))$.

Comment: Does the reverse also stand??

So, is:

$$f(n)+g(n)=\Theta (\max \{f(n),g(n) \})$$

true??

Comment: @MaryStar what u concluded about your above question? I feel yes because by reflexive nature of $\Theta$, $f(n)+g(n)=\Theta(f(n)+g(n))$ and $max\{f(n),g(n)\}=\Theta(max\{f(n),g(n)\})$. Please confirm. (just having doubt whether we can put $\Theta(max\{f(n),g(n)\})=max\{f(n),g(n)\}$)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done to prove this:

to prove: $\max(f(n),g(n))=\Theta(f(n)+g(n))$

$c_1(f(n)+g(n)) \leq\max(f(n),g(n))\leq c_2(f(n)+g(n))$

$\max(f(n),g(n)) \leq 1(f(n)+g(n))$

$\max(f(n),g(n)) \geq \frac12(f(n)+g(n))$

$\implies$ so it holds true for  $c_1\leq\frac12$ and $c_2\geq1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).