# Proving $\max(f(n), g(n)) \in \mathcal{\Omega}(f(n) + g(n))$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I was solving the problems provided in CLRS exercises and I came through this one which read:
$\max(f(n), g(n)) = \Theta(f(n) + g(n))$

I got this interesting answer and understood everything:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267255/492010

Except for one line which read:
$\max(f(n), g(n)) \in \mathcal{\Omega}(f(n) + g(n))$

As far as I have read in CLRS definition for CLRS is defined as:
$\Omega(g(n))= \{f(n):$ there exist positive constants c and $n_0$ such that $0\le c.g(n) \le f(n)$ for all $n\ge n_0$}

Coming to the answer provided. It had a line : $f(n) + g(n) \leq 2 \max(f(n),g(n))$
Following that I am confused that how come he proved that:

$max(f(n),g(n)) \in \Omega(f(n)+g(n))$

Does that mean:
$0 \le c.(f(n)+g(n))\le max(f(n),g(n))$ ?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: $max(a,b)\geq(a+b)/2$

Comment: Could you please guide me more on this.

Comment: You want to prove that there exists a constant $c$ from the last line of your question. Well, $c=0.5$ is good.

Comment: Well I need to understand how did the user prove : $max(f(n),g(n)) \in \Omega(f(n)+g(n))$

Comment: From: $f(n) + g(n) \leq 2 \max(f(n),g(n))$

Comment: You know that $max(f(n),g(n))\geq (f(n)+g(n))/2$, so the condition in $\Omega$-definition is satisfied with $c=0.5$.

Comment: But does this mean we can write the equation as: $0 \le c.(f(n)+g(n)) \le max(f(n), g(n)) ?$

Comment: I think there is an implicit assumption that the functions are nonnegative, otherwise the original problem is not quite sensible.

Comment: I agree on that. I'm a newbie to the asymptotic notations so do not have a deeper idea but still learning. Anyways. Thank you for the help. If you wish to post that as answer. I'd surely upvote that and mark it accepted as it solved my problem.